# Is syntax sweetalert wrong?

Tags: sweetalert

I'm using sweetalert in reactjs and
**strong text**why browser doesn't show 123 when I click at this button. Is  Syntax wrong?

```
        swal(
            <div>
                <button className='btn btn-danger' onClick={() => {
                    console.log(123)
                }}>confirm</button>
            </div>
        )
```

Comment: did this work for you ? can you share the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want a to console log 123 on click the confirm button then use a swal component like this :

```js
swal("Click on the button.", {
  button: "Confirm",
})
.then((value) => {
  if(value) console.log('123')
});
```

here a working [pen](https://codepen.io/HijenHEK/pen/PopZKYM) tweak it here

here is the official [sweetAlert guides](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/)

Comment: amazing, tks so much, it success

Comment: you are welcome , consider verifying the answer , here what you should do https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: it dosnt match their api, maybe it cant figure out that is a button , the syntax i shared matches their component api . visit this https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/

Comment: yeah, tks so much, I got it !